# Replacing Everything in a GitHub repo that is linked to a custom URL

Tags: git

So, I have a repo called DSU on my computer that I push to GitHub, and I have linked that repo to my custom domain, you know, mydomain.org.

Now I have done a complete overhaul of the site in another repo, REALLY on my computer.  I plan to do this: erase everything in the repo DSU, copy all of REALLY to DSU, and then push to GitHub like normal.

But boy and I afraid that weird things will happen.

Or is there a better way to do that?  What I really want to avoid is going through all the steps to link a GitHun repo to a custom URL, because that was hard for me.

But, I figure if the repo DSU on GitHub is already pointed to mydomain.org, then I can change whatever I put in that repo, and it will still be viewable at mydomain.org.

If I delete the repo on GitHub, and then create a new repo with exactly the same name, will it still link to mydomain.org?

Comment: You can quickly and easily just copy all the files from the revamped repo directory into the original, commit, and push with no issues. Note that it is generally a better idea to make all those changes in the same directory so you can make incremental changes with a clean repo history.

Comment: Thanks. But should I erase the existing files in the old repo before I copy the new repo files into it?  And should I erase the files in the GitHub repo before I push to it?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you'll have a bunch of files with no purpose. Just make sure they are committed and pushed in case you need to revert or look at the old state of the repo.

Comment: @joshmeranda it's not clear whether OP is OK with the previous version of the URL being visible in the history or not. If not, editing and pushing new commits won't suffice.